# Redirect to Google play store if required app needed by notification doesn't exist

Tags: android

I am using `NotificationManager` to display some notifications to the user on Android. When clicked on the notification, `MyApp` is supposed to launch and open a file, which it does.

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri.toString())); //uri is the custom uri which is something like 'myapp:filename' 
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent1, 0);
Notification.Builder notify = new Notification.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle("Tap here")
                    .setSmallIcon(launcher)
                    .setContentText("Some Text")
                    .setContentIntent(pintent).setAutoCancel(true);
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notificationManager.notify(0, notify.build());
```

However, what I also want is to be redirected to the `PlayStore` if the app does not exist. I do not know how to achieve this.

I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25266336/launching-an-application-if-installed-or-redirect-to-google-play) that we can use `PackageManager` to check whether the app exists or not. So, one way to achieve my goal is to go to an activity upon the clicking of notification where I check the existence of app and then decide accordingly.

What I want to know is that whether there exists a more sophisticated way to do this?

EDIT:
By sophisticated, I mean is there any other standard way to do this, or the option I suggested is the standard one.

Comment: What do you mean by sophisticated?

Comment: @miensol...by sophisticated, I mean something which doesn't need me to go to another activity, just to check if the app exists. e.g. If there is some exception, I could catch right here, or some other method. Basically, what I want to know is that whether this is the standard method which most apps use or there is some other standard method?